# Interpolation of random processes

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, interpolation

Let $\left(\Omega, \mathcal{F},  \left\{\mathcal{F}_{t}\right\}_{t\geq 0}, P \right)$ be a complete probability space with a nondecreasing family of right continuous sub-$\sigma$-algebras $\mathcal{F}$. Let $h=(h_{t}), t \geq 0$ be integer right continuous Markov chain with values in the countable set ${0,1,2,...}$, this process is a pure birth process:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
P(h_{t+\Delta t}-h_{t}=1| \mathcal{F}_{t})=a \cdot h_{t} \cdot \Delta t + o(\Delta t),\\
P(h_{t+\Delta t}-h_{t}=0| \mathcal{F}_{t})=1 - a \cdot h_{t} \cdot \Delta t + o(\Delta t), 
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
where $\Delta t \rightarrow 0, \Delta t>0, a>0$. 
$h_{t}$ - a partially observable process, we know several its values: $h_{\tau_1}, h_{\tau_2}, ..., h_{\tau_n},$
where $0 \leq \tau_1 \leq \tau_2 \leq ... \leq \tau_n$ - the moments of jumps of the homogeneous Poisson process $\pi_{t}$ with parameter $\lambda>0$.

I want to build the optimal (in a mean square error sense) estimation of $h_{s}$ for $\forall s \in [0, t]$. Seems, it is $E(h_{s}|\sigma\{w:h_{\tau_1}, h_{\tau_2}, ..., h_{\tau_n}\})$. How can I do it?

---

I have tried to use the general equation of optimal nonlinear interpolation of partially observable random process (from this book [Liptser, Shiryaev Statistics Of Random Processes](https://books.google.ru/books?id=gKtK0CjxOaIC&lpg=PA351&hl=ru&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false)):

$h_{t}$ can be represented as follows:
$$h_{t}=h_{0}+\int_{0}^{t}{a \cdot h_{s}ds}+x_{t},$$
where $(x_{t},\mathcal{F}_{t})$ is a martingale.

Let $\xi_{t}$ is a process of the observation of $h_{t}$:
$$\xi_{t}=\xi_{0}+\int_{0}^{t}{(h_{s}-\xi_{s-})d\pi_{s}}$$
$\pi_{t}$ can be represented as:
$$\pi_{t}=\lambda \cdot t + W_{t},$$ 
where $W_{t}$ - wide-sense Wiener process. So
$$h_{t}=\xi_{0}+\lambda \cdot \int_{0}^{t}{(h_{s}-\xi_{s-})d\pi_{s}}=\xi_{0}+\lambda \cdot \int_{0}^{t}{(h_{s}-\xi_{s-})d{s}}+\int_{0}^{t}{(h_{s}-\xi_{s-})d{W_{s}}}$$

The optimal estimation is $E(h_{s}|F_{t}^{\xi, \pi})$, where $F_{t}^{\xi, \pi}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\xi=(\xi_{t})$ and $\pi=(\pi_{t})$.

The problem of such representation $\xi_{t}$ that the expression $(h_{t}-\xi_{t-})$ should be different from zero:
$(h_{t}-\xi_{t-}) \geqslant C > 0$, because it is a denominator in the of $E(h_{s}|F_{t}^{\xi, \pi})$.